# how to add coupons to stripe's checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

To enable SCA changes, I am now integrating https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client stripe's (stripe v3 js file) checkout feature to my app, which makes it easy for integration of my subscription system.

**Question**

how to pass coupons to `stripe.redirectToCheckout()` method, don't see anything related to this in documentation.

**code sample**

```
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: plans_and_addons,
      successUrl: successUrl,
      cancelUrl: cancelUrl,
      clientReferenceId: customer_id, // helpful in webhook response
    })
```

Comment: Coupons don't seem to be supported at the moment but I suspect that's something on Stripe's roadmap. A temporary workaround might be to handle coupons on your own, use the server-side approach, and create a Checkout Session for an arbitrary total you wish to Charge. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#integrate

Answer (score 17):

As Daniel says above, you can't enable the promo codes when you call `redirectToCheckout` but you can enable the promo codes when you create the stripe session from your API.

So, to sum app, when you create the checkout session using `Stripe.checkout.sessions.create()` you have to also pass the `allow_promotion_codes: true` and this will actually allow you to apply promo codes to the products you have created in the stripe -> products page.

You can find more informations on this page: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/coupons/codes

Answer (score 7):

I am also facing the same issue so I contacted stripe support.

Please check the support team's reply.

> I did a thorough research on your query and I'm afraid, Checkout supports only a limited set of customizations (e.g. name, description, logo) and fields. Focusing the UI allows us to iterate on it more effectively to improve conversions and maintain support across a wide range of platforms.

They provided me one document link you can also check it. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization

I think you can solve your problem by creating custom checkout with helping stipe API. --not tried.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this, and what I've deduced from the Stripe docs is that you can't apply a coupon directly to the `redirectToCheckout` method, you have to create a Checkout session first and then use that.

- [Add a discount to Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts) the sample code is calling Checkout.session.create, not Checkout directly
- [`redirectToCheckout` Reference Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout) doesn't mention a discount or coupon parameter at all, and the sample code again is creating a Checkout session using `fetch` (to one's own server backend, which is where my expertise ceases and where I'm stifled), to generate a session ID and then passing that into the result where `redirectToCheckout` is called.